# Restrict RDS IAM DB Auth to specific db users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-iam-policy

Referring to the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.html, below command can be used to generate auth token for a user and use it to login to the database

```
aws rds generate-db-auth-token \
   --hostname rdsmysql.123456789012.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com \
   --port 3306 \
   --region us-west-2 \
   --username jane_doe
```

I have a number of RDS IAM DB users like read only, application user, admin user etc.

My question is how do I restrict, lets say AWS developer roles to only be able to generate auth token like above for a read only DB username and not admin usernames. If someone needs to generate auth token for admin users, they need to use a different AWS role to do that.
I have a pattern like all read only users will be of format *_ro, all admins will be of format *_admin.

What policy can I use to achieve this? Any examples would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't currently have an RDS with IAM Auth enabled, but you can try something like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds-db:connect",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds-db:*:ACCOUNT_ID:dbuser:*/*_ro"
        }
    ]
}
```

**rds-db:connect** is the policy that enables the token generation, and you can filter on it directly on the resource path.

Comment: Thank you so much @Filippo. Can "${aws:username}_ro" be replaced like"*_ro"? If you can point to some AWS documentation that supports this, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Take a look here for more details on the StringLike operator: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html

Comment: The key "aws:username" in the StringLike condition seems to be the aws user, not the DB user for which the policy is?

Comment: I ran some tests myself, but I couldn't get it to work. Theoretically, the last part of the Resource path is the DB user, and you should be able to filter it with a wildcard, something like arn:aws:rds-db:*:ACCOUNT_ID:dbuser:*/*_ro. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected. :("https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html

Comment: Yes looks like it doesn't support partial wildcard pattern. Its either the full db username or *

Comment: I confirm that partial wildcard like *_ro works. Thats @Filippo for the pointer.